# Compiling without -ObjC when -ObjC is required

Tags: objective-c, xcode

My Xcode project has a two frameworks: one of them requires other linker flags -ObjC in order to compile, but when the -ObjC flag is used, the second can't compile and shows many errors.

Is there a way to compile a project without the -ObjC flag when a specific framework requires it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this but it might very well work:

what -objc does is basically loading symbols (of categories) that are the linker doesn't find because they don't *seem* used. See this answer for more details:
[Why is the -ObjC linker flag needed to link categories in static libraries? (LLVM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090601/why-is-the-objc-linker-flag-needed-to-link-categories-in-static-libraries-llv)

so you should very well be able to emulate this with the -all_load linker flag

BUT that doesn't help you because that would still affect all your linked libraries

---

BUT you can tell load_all to only affect certain libs.. you'd use `-force_load %NAMEOFLIB%`

That way, you might get around -ObjC

Comment: Thank you so much. Just two questions, if you don't mind: how can I retrieve the %NAMEOFLIB% based on the Framework name that shows on the left side bar of Xcode? And should I -force_load the lib what requires -ObjC or the one that doesn't?

Comment: force load the one that requires objC.

Comment: the path should be along the lines if a.framework/libA.a or the limey - you need an a id say